# how do i can make a preview of image gallery

Tags: gallery

I have had make an image gallery using **WordPress** default gallery, with a few images, and those images has title at bottom.

I want to, when I have click to an image it being bigger and show a preview (with fade effect)

How i can do that?

**Note:** i have had tested a lot of image plugins, those was not ok to me.

Comment: i have found this plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/simplest-gallery/            it is what i was thinking to it, but seems it has no title.

Comment: have anyone better one than this ?